# XPath Query: need to get text from HTML

Tags: c#, html, xpath

I'm trying to extract the text "(TLE) THE LEARNING EXPERIENCE" from this HTML I've tried many xpath's but none seem to work. the XPath that's in the code works in Octoparse but not in the code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument document = web.Load("http://w1.lara.state.mi.us/ChildCareSearch"); //The URL to get the Info From
        HtmlNode[] textXpath_node = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//main[@id='main']/div[@class='container']/div[@class='row']/div[@class='container']/div[@class='col-sm-12']/div[2]/fieldset[@class='form-horizontal']/div[@id='SearchResultsContainer']/div[@class='pq-grid-center']/div[@class='pq-grid-cont-outer']/div[@class='pq-grid-cont']/div[@class='pq-grid-cont-inner']/table[@id='ExitTable']/tbody/tr[@class='pq-grid-row  pq-grid-oddRow '][1]/td[@id='ExitTable']/a[@class='blue-link']").ToArray(); 

        foreach (var node in textXpath_node)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPATH cant work. Why? the query is valid. By the way you can generate it with a [nice browser](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) it like this:

```
/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div/div/div/div[2]/fieldset/div[14]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/a
```

Ok but why it doesnt work either? Ok. Lets go. First, lets see what the loader load. Use a debugger and look into the `HtmlDocument`. Well. If you search for "(TLE) THE LEARNING EXPERIENCE", you wont find it. What? Hum. What if the page use ajax to load the data. It is easy to check. Open the [nice browser](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) network section and observe.

[image: network result]

Oh! You are lucky. We just find a POST request which return a json with everything! API are scraper's dream!

```
{"Data":[{"CdcLicNbr":"DC630295306","CdcName":"\u003ca class=\"blue-link\" href=\"/ChildCareSearch/Home/FacilityProfile/DC630295306\"\u003e(TLE) THE LEARNING EXPERIENCE\u003c/a\u003e","CdcAddr":"23500 ORCHARD LAKE RD. ","CdcCity":"FARMINGTON HILLS","CdcZip":"48336","CdcLicName":"TLE AT FARMINGTON HILLS LIMITED LIABILITY COMPANY","CdcType":"DC","CdcCnty":63,"CntyDesc":"OAKLAND","FacilityType":"CHILD CARE CENTER"},{"CdcLicNbr":"DC330299143","CdcName":"\u003ca class=\"blue-link\" href=\"/ChildCareSearch/Home/FacilityProfile/DC330299143\"\u003e100 ACRE WOOD DAYCARE CENTER\u003c/a\u003e","CdcAddr":"1340 ONONDAGA RD. ","CdcCity":"HOLT","CdcZip":"48842","CdcLicName":"100 ACRE WOOD DAYCARE","CdcType":"DC","CdcCnty":33,"CntyDesc":"INGHAM","FacilityType":"CHILD CARE CENTER"},{"CdcLicNbr":"DC630347309","CdcName":"\u003ca class=\"blue-link\" href=\"/ChildCareSearch/Home/FacilityProfile/DC630347309\"\u003e1ST ADVANTAGE LEARNING CENTER\u003c/a\u003e","CdcAddr":"26555 JOHN R ROAD ","CdcCity":"MADISON HEIGHTS","CdcZip":"48071","CdcLicName":"1ST ADVANTAGE LEARNING CENTER, LLC","CdcType":"DC","CdcCnty":63,"CntyDesc":"OAKLAND","FacilityType":"CHILD CARE CENTER"},{"CdcLicNbr":"DC820289306","CdcName":"\u003ca class=\"blue-link\" href=\"/ChildCareSearch/Home/FacilityProfile/DC820289306\"\u003e2 DAY\u0027S CHILD LEARNING CENTER\u003c/a\u003e","CdcAddr":"15075 MEYERS ","CdcCity":"DETROIT","CdcZip":"48227","CdcLicName":"2 DAY\u0027S CHILD LEARNING CENTER, INC.","CdcType":"DC","CdcCnty":82,"CntyDesc":"WAYNE","FacilityType":"CHILD CARE CENTER"},{"CdcLicNbr":"DF820310739","CdcName":"\u003ca class=\"blue-link\" href=\"/ChildCareSearch/Home/FacilityProfile/DF820310739\"\u003e2 SWEETS ANGELS FAMILY DAYCARE\u003c/a\u003e","CdcAddr":"9701 EVERTS STREET ","CdcCity":"DETROIT","CdcZip":"48224","CdcLicName":"SMITH-HALE, TRACY DENISE","CdcType":"DF","CdcCnty":82,"CntyDesc":"WAYNE","FacilityType":"CHILD CARE FAMILY HOME (CAPACITY 1-6)"},{"CdcLicNbr":"DC390277285","CdcName":"\u003ca class=\"blue-link\" href=\"/ChildCareSearch/Home/FacilityProfile/DC390277285\"\u003e21ST CENTURY - MILWOOD MAGNET\u003c/a\u003e","CdcAddr":"2916 KONKLE ","CdcCity":"KALAMAZOO","CdcZip":"49001","CdcLicName":"KALAMAZOO PUBLIC SCHOOLS","CdcType":"DC","CdcCnty":39,"CntyDesc":"KALAMAZOO","FacilityType":"CHILD CARE CENTER"},{"CdcLicNbr":"DC390303300","CdcName":"\u003ca class=\"blue-link\" href=\"/ChildCareSearch/Home/FacilityProfile/DC390303300\"\u003e21ST CENTURY/KCIS - HILLSIDE MIDDLE SCHOOL\u003c/a\u003e","CdcAddr":"1941 ALAMO AVE. ","CdcCity":"KALAMAZOO","CdcZip":"49006","CdcLicName":"KALAMAZOO PUBLIC SCHOOLS","CdcType":"DC","CdcCnty":39,"CntyDesc":"KALAMAZOO","FacilityType":"CHILD CARE CENTER"},{"CdcLicNbr":"DC390303302","CdcName":"\u003ca class=\"blue-link\" href=\"/ChildCareSearch/Home/FacilityProfile/DC390303302\"\u003e21ST CENTURY/KCIS - LINDEN GROVE MIDDLE SCHOOL\u003c/a\u003e","CdcAddr":"4241 ARBORETUM PKWY. ","CdcCity":"KALAMAZOO","CdcZip":"49006","CdcLicName":"KALAMAZOO PUBLIC SCHOOLS","CdcType":"DC","CdcCnty":39,"CntyDesc":"KALAMAZOO","FacilityType":"CHILD CARE CENTER"},{"CdcLicNbr":"DC390303299","CdcName":"\u003ca class=\"blue-link\" href=\"/ChildCareSearch/Home/FacilityProfile/DC390303299\"\u003e21ST CENTURY/KCIS - MAPLE STREET MAGNET\u003c/a\u003e","CdcAddr":"922 W. MAPLE ST. ","CdcCity":"KALAMAZOO","CdcZip":"49008","CdcLicName":"KALAMAZOO PUBLIC SCHOOLS","CdcType":"DC","CdcCnty":39,"CntyDesc":"KALAMAZOO","FacilityType":"CHILD CARE CENTER"},{"CdcLicNbr":"DF410384743","CdcName":"\u003ca class=\"blue-link\" href=\"/ChildCareSearch/Home/FacilityProfile/DF410384743\"\u003e3 MUSKETEERS DAYCARE\u003c/a\u003e","CdcAddr":"1388 LANCASTER AVE NW ","CdcCity":"GRAND RAPIDS","CdcZip":"49504","CdcLicName":"BIGELOW, ADELE","CdcType":"DF","CdcCnty":41,"CntyDesc":"KENT","FacilityType":"CHILD CARE FAMILY HOME (CAPACITY 1-6)"}],"TotalCount":9248,"CurrentPage":1}
```

We just transform a scraping session into a JSON parsing walk.

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3XWIie)

```
public static void Main()
{
    // we use the POST url
    var url = "http://w1.lara.state.mi.us/ChildCareSearch/Home/SearchResults";

    // we use a webclient to execute the POST request. We dont need HAP anymore
    using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        // You can change this parameters to get another page or more elements.
        var reqparm = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
        {
            {"pq_datatype", "JSON"}, {"pq_curpage", "1"}, {"pq_rpp", "10"}
        };
        var responsebytes = client.UploadValues(url, "POST", reqparm);
        var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);

       // I deserialize everthing. Look into json.net if you dont need a whole object.
        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        var name = TrimAnchor(root.Data[0].CdcName);
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}

// Feel free to fix and enhance this quick made <a> trimmer
public static string TrimAnchor(string node)
{
    return node.Substring(node.IndexOf('>') + 1).Replace("</a>","");
}

public class Datum
{
    public string CdcLicNbr { get; set; }
    public string CdcName { get; set; }
    public string CdcAddr { get; set; }
    public string CdcCity { get; set; }
    public string CdcZip { get; set; }
    public string CdcLicName { get; set; }
    public string CdcType { get; set; }
    public int CdcCnty { get; set; }
    public string CntyDesc { get; set; }
    public string FacilityType { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Datum> Data { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
}
```